# Carriage return \r on bash script

Tags: bash, sh

I have this bash script on my CentOS 5.3.

```
#!/bin/bash

RESULT=$(cat /tmp/logfile.log | grep -i "Backlog File Count" | awk '{print $6}')

if [ "${RESULT}" -lt "5" ];
  then
      echo "${RESULT} is less than 5"
  else
      echo "${RESULT} is greater than 5"
fi
```

/tmp/logfile.log:

```
Backlog File Names (first 1 files)
```

This bash script should supposedly to get the value "1" on the log file and print the output. However, when I run the script, this is the error message:

```
: integer expression expected
```

So when I set the debug mode, I found the "RESULT" variable output:

```
+ RESULT=$'1\r'
.....
+ '[' $'1\r' -lt 5 ']'
```

I've noticed that "\r" output is attached on the value.

I would appreciate if any one could lead me why there is "\r" on that output and how to get rid of that error. I tried on CentOS 6.3 and there is no issue.

```
# rpm -qa bash
bash-3.2-32.el5_9.1
```

Thank you.
James

Answer (score 4):

Your input file contains CR+LF line endings.  Strip the CR before reading the variable.  Say:

```
RESULT=$(tr -d '\r' < /tmp/logfile.log | grep -i "Backlog File Count" | awk '{print $6}')
```

Alternatively, you could remove the carriage returns from the input file by using `dos2unix` or any other utility.

---

Moreover, saying:

```
cat file | grep foobar
```

is equivalent to saying:

```
grep foobar file
```

and avoids the [Useless Use of Cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: I have tried dos2unix filename filename and it doesn't work out too. But with what you've suggested, it's working well. Thanks!

Comment: A single \r is a mac line break. You should have used mac2unix.